# bash read google calendar

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I'm looking for a way to read the events in a google calendar using bash scripts.

[gcalcli](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli) was a good solution but it's no longer developed.

Do you know of any alternative methods of reading the events of a google calendar using bash scripts?

Comment: Google calendar offers ical access, which means you don't need anything Google calendar-specific, and any ical client and client library would do. Can you describe what you want to be able to do from within your scripts? Are you set on shell scripting? I ask because handling calendars would sure sounds like something much easier done using e.g. Python, where your language gives you nice tools to calculate times and dates, update dictionaries, read databases and handle strings...

Comment: I had written a few bash scripts that read a google calendar and sent an SMS reminder before an appointment. gcalcli was great for this, but I will follow your suggestion and see if there's a way to use ical. I'm not really familiar with python.

Comment: that's a good reason *not* to use a language  – use what you're familiar with! But learning Python honestly isn't hard if you've come to grips with shell languages, and opens you a wide field of things that you can automate/program.